# If $|a\cap b|$ is even for all $a\in A,b\in B$, where $A,B\subseteq\wp(\{1,\ldots,n\})$, then $|A|\cdot|B|\le2^n$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $A,B\subseteq\wp(\{1,2,\ldots,n\})$ be such that $|a\cap b|$ is even for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Show that $|A|\cdot|B|\le 2^n$.

Bit unsure how to go about approaching this.

edit: don't seem to be able to post a response but thanks for the solution- very insightful!

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ subsets of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @Dedalus: No, they’re elements of $A$ and $B$. They’re subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: what is the name of that notation?

Comment: @Omnitic: Which notation?

Comment: the weird letter, does it mean the set of all subsets of a set? The squigly one. Found it, its called weisterstrass p and it denotes the power set.

Comment: @Omnitic: Yes, I use it for the power set because it looks like my handwritten symbol, and I have no use for the Weierstrass $\wp$ function.

Answer (score 4):

For each subset $a$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ let $\chi_a$ be the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $a$, and think of $\chi_a$ as an element of the vector space $\Bbb F_2^n$. Let $S_A=\{\chi_a:a\in A\}$ and $S_B=\{\chi_b:b\in B\}$. For each $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ we have $$\chi_a\cdot\chi_b=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\chi_a(k)\chi_b(k)\right)\bmod 2=0\;,$$ since $|a\cap b|$ is even. In other words, every vector in $S_A$ is orthogonal to every vector in $S_B$. Let $V_A=\operatorname{span}S_A$ and $V_B=\operatorname{span}S_B$; then $V_B\subseteq V_A^\perp$, so $$\dim V_A+\dim V_B\le\dim V_A+\dim V_A^\perp=n\;.$$

A subspace of $\Bbb F_2^n$ of dimension $d$ has cardinality $2^d$, so ... ?